# Intermediary result for Novikov sufficient condition

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus

In proposition 13.1 of the book "stochastic calculus and financial applications" by Steele,

It says that

> for all $\lambda \leqslant 0$, we have the identity $E[M_{\tau_a}(\lambda\mu) = 1$

Where $$M_t(\mu) = exp(\int^t_0\mu(\omega,s)dB_s-\frac{1}{2}\int^t_0\mu^2(\omega,s)ds)\text{ for }\mu\in L^2_{Loc}$$

$$\tau_a = inf\{t\ \vert\ Y_t = -a \text{ or } t>T\}$$ is a stopping time for the following $$Y_t = \int^t_0\mu(\omega,s)dB_s -\int_0^t\mu^2(\omega,s)ds$$

and $\lambda$ smaller than 1

The proof says that $$M_{\tau_a}(\lambda\mu) = 1+\int^{\tau_a}_0\lambda\mu(\omega,s)M_s(\lambda\mu)dB_S\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

and then it says that to prove the result, it suffices to show that the integrand is in $H^2$ i.e. $$E\left[\int^{\tau_a}_0\mu^2(\omega,s)M_s^2(\lambda\mu)ds\right] < \infty\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

Why is this a sufficient condition?

All it says is that the integral in the right side of (1) is finite but we want it to be 0 whe, we take the mean.

Comment: There are multiple books called "Stochastic Calculus" - which one are you talking about? What is $M$? What is $\tau_a$? What is $\lambda\mu$?

Comment: I added it in the question :)

Comment: At a first glance, I think that (1) must come from Ito's lemma, and the "sufficient condition" would verify that the hypotheses of the lemma are satisfied.

Comment: Yes (1) comes from previous calculations and Ito's lemma. But why would (2) be sufficient to prove the result? What I would want to do is apply $E$ on (1) and show that $E(\int_0^{\tau_a} (...)] = 0$.